# Head runs, a question on Probability Theory and Examples by Rick Durrett

Tags: probability

The model is the following. Let $X_n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be i.i.d with $P(X_n = 1) = P(X_n = -1) = 1/2$. Let $l_n = \max\{m : X_{n-m+1} = ... = X_n = 1\}$, and let $L_n = \max_{1 \leq m \leq n} l_m$.

If we consider two-sided sequence so that for all $n$, $P(l_n = k) = (1/2)^{k+1}$ for $k \geq 0$.

My question is about the sentence "Since $l_1 < \infty$, the result we are going to prove $L_n/\log_2 n \to 1 \ a.s.$ is also true for a one-sided sequence. "

1. Why $l_1 < \infty$? I think the reason is $P(l_1 = k) = (1/2)^k \to 0, k \to \infty$. I want to clarify this point.
2. Why $l_1 < \infty$ means that the conclusion is also true for the one-sided sequence? In other words, I don't know the effect of $l_1 < \infty$ in this proof.

The following is the proof in the book. This's on the book, Probability Theory and Examples Version 5 by Rick Durrett. It's on P63, Example 2.3.12.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Imagine positioning yourself at time 1, and starting to flip coins *backwards* in time (with the first flip at time 1). Observe that the number of flips until the first tails is observed is exactly the same as the distribution of $\ell_1$. Thus, $\ell_1$ has a Geometric(1/2) distribution, and indeed $\ell_1 < \infty$ almost surely, pretty much because of the reason you suggested. (To prove it, note that $\{ X = \infty \} = \bigcap_{k \geq 1} \{ X > k \}$, so $\mathbb{P}(\ell_1 = \infty) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X > k) = 0$ for any random variable $X$ with a non-degenerate CDF.)
2. Suppose that $\tilde{L}_n$ is the length of the longest head run for the one-sided sequence (i.e. we start flipping from time 1 going forwards in time). Note that $\tilde{L}_n$ and $L_n$ are essentially the same, with the difference possible being caused by a longer head run due to a sequence of heads before time 1 in the two-sided sequence. By adjusting for this and then dividing by $\log_2 n$, we obtain the inequalities
   $$
   \frac{L_n - \ell_1}{\log_2 n} \leq \frac{\tilde{L}_n}{\log_2 n} \leq \frac{L_n}{\log_2 n} .
   $$
   Since $\ell_1 < \infty$ almost surely, we have $\frac{\ell_1}{\log_2 n} \to 0$ almost surely (i.e. for every $\omega$ in this event, $\ell_1 \leq K < \infty$ for some number $K = K(\omega)$ and $\frac{K}{\log_2 n} \to 0$). Therefore, on the additional almost sure event $\frac{L_n}{\log_2 n} \to 1$, both sides of the inequality tend to one, and by sandwiching we deduce that $\frac{\tilde{L}_n}{\log_2 n} \to 1$ almost surely as well.